# python dataframe pandas drop multiple column using column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand that to drop a column you use `df.drop('column name', axis=1, inplace  =True)`

The file format is in `.csv` file

I want to use above syntax for large data sets and more in robust way

suppose I have 500 columns and I want to keep column no 100 to 140 using column name not by indices and rest want to drop , how would I write  above syntax so that I can achieve my goal and also in 100 to 140 column , I want to drop column no 105, 108,110 by column name

Comment: Why are you referring to column's position, if you want to drop them by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = df.loc[:, 'col_100_name' : 'col_140_name']
```

`.loc` always selects using both ends inclusive. Here I am selecting all rows, and only the columns that you want to select (by names).

After this (or before - it doesn't matter) you can drop the other columns by names as usual:

```py
df.drop(['col_105_name', 'col_108_name', 'col_110_name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

If you wish to select columns **using a combination of slices and explicit column names:**

```py
cols_in_the_slice = df.loc[:, 'col_100_name' : 'col_140_name'].columns
other_cols = pd.Index(['col_02_name', 'col_04_name'])
all_cols = other_cols.union(cols_in_the_slice , sort=False)

df = df[all_cols]
```

Union appends the NEW (not yet encountered) elements of `cols_in_the_slice` to the end of `other_cols`. It sorts by default, so I specify `sort=False` not to sort. Then we are selecting all these columns.

By the way, here you can also drop column names which you don't wish to have.

You can use [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop.html) if you know column names, or [`.delete`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.delete.html) if you know their locations in this index:

```py
cols_in_the_slice = cols_in_the_slice.drop(['col_105_name', 'col_108_name', 'col_110_name'])
```

I also recommend taking a look at [Pandas User Guide on Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: here when I am using - df = df.loc[:,  'col_02_name', 'col_04_name',  'col_100_name' : 'col_140_name'] saying - too many indexes
basically I also want to keep 2 more individuals columns along with 100 to 140

Comment: Yes - too many indices because there can exist only 1 'from' and 1 'to' endpoints.

Comment: very impressed with your way of answering
thnx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a string parameter for the column name, use a list of strings refering to the column names you want to delete.